# Skip super call while testing method using PowerMockito

Tags: java, testing, powermock

Is it possible to skip super method ("super.start()") for testing, for example:

```
public void start() {
   super.start();
   //other methods which I really want to test
}
```

Edited: Forgot to mention - I don't want to change original code.

Answer (score 0):

I would move other methods to a separate method

```
public void start() {
   super.start();
   start0();
}

void start0() {
  //other methods which you really want to test
}
```

this would make the class better testable

Comment: "Testable" - is not a good reason for changing a source code (when there is no other reasons, of course)

Comment: @XZen I dissagree, testability is a quality attribute of good software, and should not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like it's possible, please checkout the example:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Example.B.class)
public class Example {

  @Test
  public void testSuppressMethod() throws Exception {
    suppress(method(A.class, "doA"));
    new B().doA();
  }

  static class A {
    void doA() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
  }

  static class B extends A {
    @Override
    void doA() {
        super.doA();
        System.out.println("b");
    }
  }
}
```

All you need is to specify parent class in suppress statement.
PowerMock 1.5.1 used.